# Create fancybox gallery from multiple divs after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I am working with fancybox2 and want to create a nice clickable fancybox with case studies from reference projects.

The idea is to have one link `<a class="fbajax fancybox.ajax" href="filename">` on a page that triggers a file (.txt for the moment, should be replaced by a .php file in the future) to be opend in a fancybox.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fbajax").fancybox({
    });
  });
</script>
```

Within the file there are several div containers `<div class="fb2wrap">` each containing the content from a single case study.

At the moment all `<div class="fb2wrap">` are listed on one fancybox item. How can I make fancybox to create a gallery from my div containers to make the case studies clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea : you need to adapt the content of the fancybox before this content is loaded, so you can define a `beforeLoad` callback as described here : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

But the simplest way to achieve it is to create a web page for each case study, and adapt this small jsfiddle i created by replacing the `href=#caseStudyX` of each link by `href=caseStudyX.php`

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xavier_seignard/RDv2a/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As I'm not that familiar with jquery i won't try to create a beforeLoad callback to attach content from another file to the fancybox. I'll keep to you second approch, create a php file for each case study and link them in my fancybox. I'm thinking of creating an overview page after clicking on the case study link on my frontpage because I don't want to implement a bunch of hidden links ;)

Comment: yes, it's up to you. but you got the big picture. have fun with fancybox